# MYSQL - how to get all records from specific record

Tags: mysql

I have been trying hard to find how to get all records from specific record in a sql query. I am able to do it in a different way but looks unprofessional.

For example, I have following table

```
-----------------------
id  name  sessionid
-----------------------
1  dav    88
2  dav    88
3  dav    99
4  po     100
5  nav    111
6  dav    99
7  nav    120
```

I would like to fetch all records from id 3 to id 7 and the result should look like this

```
-----------------------
id  name  sessionid
-----------------------
3  dav    99
4  po     100
5  nav    111
6  dav    99
7  nav    120
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please show any code attempts you have made.

Comment: hi ford i done in php with multiple queries and if conditions... but its bit messy... :)

Comment: Am I missing something?

Comment: What criteria do you use to determine that you must bring the ids from 3 to 7?

Comment: sessionid @Jodevan.....

Comment: Could you please clarify? How can this column determine what needs to be retrieved? Should it be between a specific range? Should it be greater than some value? Currently it's impossible to guess how to bring the data you need.

Comment: for example user login with session id 99, i would like to show all records from session id  first matched. in above case user first record is mataching from id 3 so all records from id3 will fetch... @Jodevan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your last comment, I'll give it a try:

```
select *
from x
where id >= (
    select min(id)
    from x
    where sessionid = 99
)
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: I think you might have cracked it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it just this?

```
SELECT * FROM table where table.id BETWEEN 3 AND 7
```

Comment: how to find its strating from 3, if there are hunderds of records

Comment: Based on his actual question, this is a valid answer.

Comment: @Jodevan yeah, I get the feeling there is something we're all missing though